# Streaming audio from microphone using Pyjnius for android

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, pyjnius

I am developing cross-platforms using Kivy and I want to use Pyjnius to push and get bytes to the speaker or microphone for android(for windows and Linux Pyaudio works fine),I have tried Plyer and audiostream, but both them are not well maintained.

i would like to work on this problem, but i dont know where to start.

Note: the kivy app is build and installed without any error in logcat and i used the example provided by audiostream.and callback function didnot fire
https://github.com/kivy/audiostream/blob/master/examples/record_mac.py